# can I conclude that image of a function is bijective to its domain by proving its injective?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have a homomorphism (function) $\phi: G_1 \longrightarrow G_2$
and I have showed that $\phi$ is injective (I showed that kernel($\phi$) = identity of $G_1$)

can I conclude that $G_1 \cong im(\phi)$? in other words, is $G_1$ isomorphic to the image of $\phi$? I think the definition of a "image" implies the **onto** property?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $G$ modulo the kernel is isomorphic to the image.  If the kernel is trivial then $G$ is isomorphic to the image.  I assume we are talking about groups here.

Comment: Do I need to construct a new function $\phi_1: G_1 \longrightarrow im(\phi)$ where $\phi_1(x) = \phi(x)$ and show that is new function is a homomorphism+injective+surjective? Since this is usually how I prove isomorphism

Comment: I don't think that's necessary since $\phi_1$ is identical to $\phi$.  Just say it's the restriction to the range being the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Surjectivity is not as intrinsic as injectivity is. It depends on the choice of the codomain. As you say, you can make any function surjective by changing the codomain to be the image.